# ¿Cómo conectarme a instancia remota de WildFly utilizando JMC?

Tags: java, wildfly, jmc

Adaptado del sitio en inglés: https://stackoverflow.com/q/36750032/1065197

---

Tengo un servidor Linux donde estoy ejecutando WildFly 10. Trabajo en un equipo Windows y quiero evaluar el rendimiento del servidor de aplicaciones remoto. He verificado que el puerto 9990 está habilitado para acceder mediante http con la URL `http://<ip>:9990/console` y mediante JMX desde el cliente JConsole que viene en WildFly. Para este último, descargué WildFly a mi equipo, ejecuté `%WILDFLY_PATH%\bin\jconsole.bat`, me conecté utilizando `service:jmx:http-remoting-jmx://<ip>:9990` y mis credenciales, funciona perfecto. Ahora quiero acceder mediante JMC, pero no puedo lograrlo. Lo que intenté:

- Copié la librería jboss-client.jar de `%WILDFLY_PATH%\bin\client` a `%JDK_HOME%\lib\missioncontrol\dropins` e iniciar JMC.
- Ejecuté JMC desde línea de comandos y agregué el parámetro `-cp:a <location of jboss-client.jar>`, así:

  ```
  jmc.exe -cp:a "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_72\lib\missioncontrol\dropins\jboss-client.jar"
  ```

  Ninguna de estas funcionó.

Intenté acceder con VisualVM y funcionó utilizando el último método pero reemplazando `jmc.exe` por `jvisualvm.exe` y pude conectarme a la VM remota sin problemas. Me pregunto si hay alguna manera de lograrlo con JMC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Luego de por fin encontrar [la documentación de JMC](https://docs.oracle.com/javacomponents/index.html) (porque el enlace a la documentación desde el [sitio oficial de JMC](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaseproducts/mission-control/java-mission-control-1998576.html) está roto), en la parte final pude dar con la sección de [Preguntas Frecuentes](http://docs.oracle.com/javacomponents/jmc-5-5/jmc-user-guide/faq.htm) que explica cómo conectarse a JBoss (al parecer no soy el único que en algún momento ha sufrido con esto). El texto explica:

> Before starting JMC, you need to add the `-Xbootclasspath/a` option to the `-vmargs` section of the `jmc.ini` file. The value for this option (after a colon) should be set to the extended classpath that is generated by JBoss's `jconsole.bat` file (for this, add `@echo on` to the file and run it).

Traducido a español:

> Antes de iniciar JMC, necesitas agregar la opción `-Xbootclasspath/a` a la sección `-vmargs` del archivo `jmc.ini`. El valor de esta opción (luego de dos puntos) deberá configurarse para incluir el uso de las librerías que genera el archivo `jconsole.bat` de JBoss (para esto, agrega `@echo on` en el archivo y ejecútalo).

Traducido a buen cristiano:

1. Acceder a `%WILDFLY_PATH%\bin`, donde `%WILDFLY_PATH%` es la ruta donde has instalado/desempaquetado WildFly.
2. Editar el archivo jconsole.bat. En la primera línea, cambiar la sentencia `@echo off` por `@echo on`, esto permitirá que la salida a consola sea visible.
3. Ejecutar jconsole.bat. Se abrirá una consola y luego la ventana de JConsole. Lo importante aquí es el contenido impreso en la consola. En la parte final de los mensajes, verás un mensaje con un contenido similar a este:

   ```
   <Unidad>:\ruta\de\wildfly-10.0.0.Final\bin>if "" == "" ("C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_72\bin\jconsole.exe" "-J-Djava.class.path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_72\lib\jconsole.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_72\lib\tools.jar;<Unidad>:\ruta\de\wildfly-10.0.0.Final\bin\client\jboss-cli-client.jar" )  else ("C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_72\bin\jconsole.exe" "-J-Djava.class.path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_72\lib\jconsole.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_72\lib\tools.jar;<Unidad>:\ruta\de\wildfly-10.0.0.Final\bin\client\jboss-cli-client.jar"  )
   ```

   Lo principal es obtener el valor de la variable `-J-Djava.class.path` para la condición que se cumpla de acuerdo al mensaje de log. En este caso, como la condición es: `"" == ""`, tomaré el resultado de la primera parte:

   ```
   C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_72\lib\jconsole.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_72\lib\tools.jar;<Unidad>:\ruta\de\wildfly-10.0.0.Final\bin\client\jboss-cli-client.jar
   ```
4. Acceder a `%JDK_HOME%\bin` y ubicar el archivo jmc.ini. Abrirlo con un editor (Recomendación: sacar una copia al archivo antes de modificarlo). En la parte final, agregar una línea con el contenido `-Xbootclasspath/a:` y luego colocar el contenido que obtuvimos de JConsole. Para este ejemplo, la línea sería como sigue:

   ```
   -Xbootclasspath/a:C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_72\lib\jconsole.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_72\lib\tools.jar;<Unidad>:\ruta\de\wildfly-10.0.0.Final\bin\client\jboss-cli-client.jar
   ```

   (Se entiende que la parte de `<Unidad>:\ruta\de\` debe ser reemplazada por la unidad y ruta donde está wildfly, por favor no copiar y pegar directamente).
5. Guardar los cambios realizados. Iniciar jmc que se encuentra en esa ruta.

Una vez realizados estos cambios, ya pude acceder a mi servidor Wildfly de manera remota y aprovechar los beneficios de JMC para la evaluación de rendimiento, memoria, entre otros.